# SQL - if col1 have value expect 0 and col2 have value except 0 with same value for col3 then values in one row

Tags: mysql

I have one table with these value

```
col1                    col2                 col3         
----------------------  -------------------  -------------------------
                     1                    0  ADD SERVICE ACTIVITY 1   
                     0                    1  ADD SERVICE ACTIVITY 1   
                     0                    8  Docment testing 2 (C07)
```

I want result like:

```
col1                    col2                 col3         
----------------------  -------------------  -------------------------
                     1                    1  ADD SERVICE ACTIVITY 1   
                     0                    8  Docment testing 2 (C07)
```

Comment: What if the second record not had `ADD SERVICE ACTIVITY 1` but `ADD SERVICE ACTIVITY 2` instead? would it still merge into one record like that?

Comment: Somehow a [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) comes to mind to get the max of the col1 and col2 columns.. But hard to answer without some more records in the example data or how it should merge when the  col3 is different between records.

Comment: Do you mean any of [these queries](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCqySHzLjRER7PiGWEPEb8/0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to `group` your data by column `col3`. I'm not sure whether results for `col1` and `col2` are sums or max values.

```
--for MAX:
SELECT MAX(COL1) as col1, MAX(COL2) as col2, COL3
/*-- for SUM:
SELECT SUM(COL1) as col1, SUM(COL2) as col2, COL3
*/
FROM test
GROUP BY COL3;
```

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, consider accepting it